# JSON formatting for SharePoint 2019 calculated columns Help

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-experience, json-formatting, 2019, column-formatting

Can someone help me apply JSON formatting to this calculated column to display the icons again?

```
="<DIV align='center'><img src='/sites/test/images/"&IF([ProjectHealth]="GREEN","bgrn.png",)&IF([ProjectHealth]="RED","bred.png",)&IF([ProjectHealth]="YELLOW","byel.png",)&"'></DIV>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON formatting like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "attributes": {
    "src": "='/sites/test/images/' + if([$ProjectHealth] == 'GREEN', 'bgrn.png', if([$ProjectHealth] == 'RED', 'bred.png', if([$ProjectHealth] == 'YELLOW', 'byel.png', 'default.png')))"
  }
}
```

Where `ProjectHealth` is internal name of your column. You can find the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

---

If you are applying this JSON on `ProjectHealth` column, you can also use:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "attributes": {
    "src": "='/sites/test/images/' + if(@currentField == 'GREEN', 'bgrn.png', if(@currentField == 'RED', 'bred.png', if(@currentField == 'YELLOW', 'byel.png', 'default.png')))"
  }
}
```

**Documentation**: [column-formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

---

**Update**:

As you are using SharePoint 2019, you may need to convert the above expression in `src` property using **Abstract Syntax Tree expressions**.

For more information, check: [Abstract Syntax Tree expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#abstract-syntax-tree-expressions)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "attributes": {
    "src": {
      "operator": "+",
      "operands": [
        "/sites/test/images/",
        {
          "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "=",
              "operands": [
                "[$ProjectHealth]",
                "GREEN"
              ]
            },
            "bgrn.png",
            {
              "operator": "?",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "=",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$ProjectHealth]",
                    "RED"
                  ]
                },
                "bred.png",
                {
                  "operator": "?",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "=",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$ProjectHealth]",
                        "YELLOW"
                      ]
                    },
                    "byel.png",
                    "default.png"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```